# define and initialize array for stdin, stdout and stderr

Tags: c

Below is a copy of some code from the book "The C Programming Language, Second Edition" by K&R. I have no idea how these `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr` can be defined and initialized as this way. Please help me with an explanation.

```
FILE _iob[OPEN_MAX] = {
    {0, (char *) 0, (char *) 0, _READ, 0},
    {0, (char *) 0, (char *) 0, _WRITE, 1},
    {0, (char *) 0, (char *) 0, _WRITE | _UNBUF, 2}
};
```

Comment: What's the trouble?  Don't you understand initializing arrays of structures?  Have you seen how `stdin` etc are defined?  Have you read the code that used to illustrate all this?  Note that while this type of code has a long history (Version 7 Unix through System V Release 4, for example), modern GNU C Library handles things quite differently.  (Are you sure you copied the initialization properly?  Isn't the middle line given a `1`, not a `0` as the last initializer?)

Comment: Maybe get a book that wasn't written before Wild Thing.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, Thanks for your reply. Yes my question seems not on a point which makes some confusion.  my understanding to this one {0, (char *) 0, (char *) 0, _READ, 0} being initialized as stdin. {0, (char *) 0, (char *) 0, _WRITE, 1}, being initialized as stdout, {0, (char *) 0, (char *) 0, _WRITE | _UNBUF, 2} being initialized as stderr. then why each array hold 5 elements and what each of elements mean? i should have to go read a thing like stdin, am i right? then i will understand why put 5 elements for each array of stdin, stdout and stderr. that is middle line, i check book again

Answer (score 2):

This code

```
FILE _iob[OPEN_MAX] = {
    {0, (char *) 0, (char *) 0, _READ, 0},
    {0, (char *) 0, (char *) 0, _WRITE, 1},
    {0, (char *) 0, (char *) 0, _WRITE | _UNBUF, 2}
};
```

is just an example of code that might be used to initialize a *specific example of an implementation* of `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` FILE structures.

It is nothing more than how **that specific example implementation might be initialized** and has nothing to do with any Linux, glibc, Windows, or any other real-world `FILE` implementation you'll ever run into.

The code you posted has five values for each array element because that's what the implementation example uses in its `FILE` structure.  Those elements and their values are specific only to that example implementation.